# Converting NULL values to "UNKNOWN" without knowing column type

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I've got several databases that I'm trying to query on my website with the same SQL code. I'm passing the column names/table that I'd like to use via URL to a new page. For example:

`/some/url.php?table=tableName&c1=ColumnOne&c2=ColumnTwo&c3=ColumnThree&n=3`

I have several of these URLs that all link to the same page (but with different table names and columns). On the next page, the PHP code would be something like this

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= $n; $j++) {
    // Since the number of column variables varies (there could be c1 and c2, or c1 -> c5), you need to save this part of the query in a variable
    $variables .= ${'c' . $j} . ', ';
}

SELECT $variables
FROM db.dbo.tableName
```

So the actual query for these 3 columns would be

```
SELECT ColumnOne, ColumnTwo, ColumnThree
FROM db.dbo.tableName
```

The problem is that some of the columns are float and some are nvarchar(254). In the float columns, the null values are 0. In the nvarchar(254) columns, null values are just NULL. I need the NULL values in nvarchar(254) columns to be "UNKNOWN", and the 0 values in float columns to also be "UNKNOWN".

This is an example of what I mean. ColumnOne and ColumnTwo are float, while ColumnThree is nvarchar(254).

```
---------------------------------------------
|ColumnOne    |ColumnTwo     |ColumnThree   |
---------------------------------------------
|0            |142563        |Insert        |
---------------------------------------------
|1            |348           |Some          |
---------------------------------------------
|2            |2535          |NULL          |
---------------------------------------------
|3            |0             |Value         |
---------------------------------------------
|0            |82536         |NULL          |
---------------------------------------------
|5            |0             |Here          |
---------------------------------------------
```

Here is what I would like it to look like

```
---------------------------------------------
|ColumnOne    |ColumnTwo     |ColumnThree   |
---------------------------------------------
|UNKNOWN      |142563        |Insert        |
---------------------------------------------
|1            |348           |Some          |
---------------------------------------------
|2            |2535          |UNKNOWN       |
---------------------------------------------
|3            |UNKNOWN       |Value         |
---------------------------------------------
|UNKNOWN      |82536         |UNKNOWN       |
---------------------------------------------
|5            |UNKNOWN       |Here          |
---------------------------------------------
```

I've tried this

```
SELECT ISNULL(ColumnOne, 'UNKNOWN'), ISNULL(ColumnTwo, 'UNKNOWN'), ISNULL(ColumnThree, 'UNKNOWN')
FROM db.dbo.tableName
```

However, I'm getting this error: `Error converting data type varchar to float`

Can someone help me out? It would be greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT: I know that to convert 0 values to UNKNOWN in float columns, I need to do this

`(CASE WHEN ColumnOne = 0 THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE CAST(ColumnOne AS varchar(255)) END)`

and to convert the NULL values to UNKNOWN in nvarchar(254) columns, I need to do this

`ISNULL(ColumnOne, 'UNKNOWN')`

I just don't know the column type. Is there any way to do a CASE statement to check the column type, then use the appropriate one?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of presentation issue that the application should handle, not the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have word `UNKNOWN` selected along float values in your float column. You need to convert all float values to varchar. After converting you can easily replace 0 or NULL with other word.

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST(ColumnOne AS NVARCHAR(254)),'0'),'UNKNOWN')
FROM db.dbo.tableName
```

(this is first replacing all zeros with NULL, then replace all NULLS with 'UNKNOWN' - making sure both 0 and NULL are replaced)

Since converting varchar to varchar will do no harm, yo can use same syntax for all columns if you don't know dynamically which are which.

```
SELECT 
  ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST(ColumnOne AS NVARCHAR(254)),'0'),'UNKNOWN') as ColumnOne
 ,ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST(ColumnTwo AS NVARCHAR(254)),'0'),'UNKNOWN') as ColumnTwo
 ,ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST(ColumnThree AS NVARCHAR(254)),'0'),'UNKNOWN') as ColumnThree
FROM db.dbo.tableName
```

**[SQLFiddleDEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f6ac/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can not store Varchar values in column type Float. You have to change the column type to varchar to store "Unknown" value. 
Also, if you don't want to change the column type, then while fetching your result set Convert float value(0) to Varchar and then replace it with "Unknown"

```
select (Case Convert(varchar(500),Column1) when '0' Then 'Unknown' 
when null then 'Unknown' Else  Column1 end)Column1
```

Here I'm first Converting the values to varchar, Then if the value is 0, it will convert it to Null and then replace Null with 'Unknown'

Comment: This works for converting 0 values in float columns to UNKNOWN, but I don't know the column type, so I need something that I can use for both types. Is there any way to use a CASE statement to figure out the type, and only use this on float columns?

Comment: I've edited my query, this would work with all the column types, and whether its 0 or Null it will convert it to 'Unknown'

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert non-character column values to character in order that all possible output values of the function will have the same type.  Use the `Str()` function

```
SELECT ISNULL(Str(ColumnOne, 8,4), 'UNKNOWN'), 
       ISNULL(str(ColumnTwo, 8,4), 'UNKNOWN'), 
       ISNULL(Str(ColumnThree, 8, 4), 'UNKNOWN')
 FROM db.dbo.tableName
```

do this for all columns that are not already VARCHAR